# Decomposition and invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\sigma$ be a linear operator on $V$. And $w$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, $W=\langle w\rangle$ (i.e.  $\sigma|_{W}=\operatorname{Id}$),  and also $\sigma|_{V/W}=\operatorname{Id}$. It seems to me, that the previous assumptions imply that $\sigma$ is either identity map or $\sigma$ has no $\sigma$-invariant vector spaces which have trivial intersection with $W$ and thus $V$ is 2-dimensional and in some basis  $\sigma$ is $\begin{pmatrix}{1\;1 \\0\;1}\end{pmatrix}$. I also feel that this is not that simple, so can someone make it clear?

Comment: I would think $\sigma$ is the identity. Complete $w$ in a basis. $\sigma(v) = v$ for each $v$ in the basis so $\sigma = id_V$.

Comment: @N.H. $\sigma$ is not necessarily be identity, patricularly because of my counterexample above :)

Comment: @N.H. Generally, $\sigma(v+W)=v+W$ does not mean that $\sigma(v)=v$. It is also possible $\sigma(v)= v+ \alpha w$

Comment: Ok $V/W$ was the quotient vector space, I was thinking it was the complement of $W$ in $V$ ... Sorry.

Comment: @N.H., exactly. thanks for response anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $W \subseteq V$ with $\sigma|_{W} = \operatorname{Id}$ and $\sigma|_{V/W} = \operatorname{Id}$. Set $W = W_1$ and choose a complement $W_2$ with $W_1 \oplus W_2 = V$. Given $w = w_1 + w_2$, we have $\sigma(w) = w_1 + w_2 + *$ where $* \in W_1$ and so with respect to an appropriate choice of basis $\mathcal{B} = (v_1, \dots, v_k, v_{k-1}, \dots, v_n)$ for $V$ (where $(v_i)_{i=1}^k$ is a basis for $W_1$ and $(v_i)_{i=k+1}^n$ is a basis for $W_2$), the operator has the form

$$ [\sigma]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} I_{k \times k} & * \\ 0 & I_{(n-k) \times (n-k)} \end{pmatrix}. $$

In fact, operator which can be represented by such a matrix will have the property that $\sigma|_{W_1} = \operatorname{Id}$ and $\sigma|_{V/W_1} = \operatorname{Id}$ where $W_1 = \left< v_1, \dots, v_k \right>$. There is no reason for $V$ to be two-dimensional.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question was not complete, it is given that $ dimW=1$.

Comment: and in my conditions it just mean that except $\sigma = Id$ we just have a case where $\sigma$ is $\begin{pmatrix}{1\;1\;0 \\ 0\;1\;0\\ 0\;0\;I} \end{pmatrix}$, am I right?

Comment: In your case, $\dim W = k = 1$ and so if $\dim V = n$ the matrix representation of the operator can have $n - 1$ free entries. For example, $\sigma$ whose matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ sastfies your conditions.

Comment: and what about Jordan canonical form of your matrix?:)

Comment: what's written above is the canonical form of $\sigma$ up to permutation of jordan block $J_2(1)$